# public char * member of a class/struct inaccessible?!?!?!po

Tags: c++, char, member

Code snippet to follow.

I have a struct (example code has class, tried both, same effect) that will store a number of char *.  I made a constructor for the class that initializes most of them to = "";
Upon attempting to modify that member of an instance of the class, strncpy et all report access denied.  These functions even report access denied when i use them in the scope of internal struct/class member functions.

Its been my assumption that having a char * member of a struct/class was no big deal and nothing special (apart from being a pointer to a char, which required that it be initialized at some point before being used, and destroyed at certain times).

I appreciate it if someone could tell me where my assumptions have been wrong, and direct me to some literature that would clarify whats going on.  I am currently compiling the code under vs2008 full edition.

I expect that someone who will run this code will get a runtime error about being denied access to a certain memory location.

I also expect that when I make a char * mystr that when I later say mystr = ""; that the memory is initialized for mystr to then be used.

I'd also like to think i'm not an idiot, but when I try to use the locals window to determine the precise in memory address of a certain variable, I can't seem to get the ide to tell me where the memory is at.  I ahve to get lucky in the memory window.  oh well.

help!  Thanks in advance.  I hate dealing with these stupid char * cuz I always mess them up somehow, and my assumptions about how they work are flawwed.  I want to change this so that I command them like the tools they are, not them frustrate me.

Thanks again for your consideration.
Josh

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



   class mystruct {
    public:
 int A;
 char* B;
 char* C;

 mystruct() {
  A = 0xFE;
  B = new char[32];
  B = "";
  C = "test";
 }

 void test(char *input) {
  strncpy(B,input, strlen(input));
 }
    };

    int main(char* argv[], int argc) {

 mystruct work;
 char wtf[32];

    // work.A = 0xbb;
 work.test("gotchabitch!");
    // sprintf(wtf, "address of work is %x" , &work);
    // strncpy(work.C,"gotchabitch!\0",strlen("gotchabitch!\0"));
  strncpy(work.B,"gotchabitch!",strlen("gotchabitch!"));
 printf("%d;%s;%s;", work.A, work.B, work.C); 

 return 0;
    }
```

Response to all:  Ok, I've learned that when you assign a string literal to a char * that you're really saying char * const B = "something".  (isn't that different from const char * B = something, where the latter is a a pointer whose address can not change, as opposed to the former which is a pointer to memory that can't be changed?).  Either way, this explains the error message that I got.  Thank you all for that.

Comment: Your final analysis is almost exactly correct... but you got the two types backward.  `const char*` is the pointer into memory that cannot be changed (like a string literal), while `char* const` is the pointer that cannot be reassigned to point to other memory, although you can make changes to the memory it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
B = new char[32];
B = "";
```

You first assign the pointer returned by `new` to `B`, then you assign a pointer to the string literal `""` to `B`, effectively overwriting the pointer returned by `new`.

[As Jonathan Leffler explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221397/public-char-member-of-a-class-struct-inaccessiblepo/3221410#3221410), string literals are read-only, so you encounter an error when you try to write to the string literal (`""`) pointed-to by `B`.

If you want to store the empty string in `B`, you need to use a library function like `strcpy()` (or preferably, a safer function, like `snprintf()`).  In this case, you could also just assign `\0` to `B[0]`, since that's the same thing.  In C and C++, you can't assign arrays (or C strings, which are just arrays of characters) using `=`.

Ideally, you should just  use `std::string` instead of raw C strings; then you don't have to worry about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you tried to do:

```
strncpy(work.C, "something", strlen(something));
```

you are copying over readonly data - which is not a good idea.  That's because the pointer, C, points to a string literal; overwriting string literals is not allowed.  Similar comments apply to B - but there you are also leaking memory.

The key point is the comment you made about 'run time' not 'compile time' error.  It is not that the member is inaccessible; it is just not abusable when you've initialized it as you have.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line:

```
C = "test";
```

in mystruct's constructor.  `"test"` is a pointer to read-only memory, it's not safe to use it to initialize a non-const pointer.  The only reason the compiler doesn't enforce this is the huge amount of C code created before people cared about const-correctness, which ought to be declared `const` but aren't.

```
B = "";
```

is likewise not type-safe.